# webpack + sass-loader: Invalid CSS after "...-width: $small)": expected "{", was ";"

Tags: css, sass, webpack, sass-loader

I've been looking for some answer to this mystical  error i keep getting, and i dont really know where else to look. Apparently, there's an offending media query selector, but it seems as normal as any other media query example i had found so far. (Also, im not very good with media queries, really, but i think they are well formed):

```
$small: 480px
$medium: 786px
$large: 1140px


@media only screen and (min-width: $small)

@media only screen and (min-width: $medium)
    .some-selector
        border: 1px solid #dedede
        border-radius: 6px
        bottom: 10px
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        height: 500px
        position: absolute
        right: 10px
        width: 320px
         .
         .
         .
```

The error i get is:

```
Module build failed: 
@media only screen and (min-width: $small)
                                        ^
      Invalid CSS after "...-width: $small)": expected "{", was ";"
      in /path/to/mediaqueries.sass (line 6, column 42)
```

I get this error when I use webpack for transpiling using a stack of many loaders for processing the stylesheets. The webpack configuration for processing .sass files is:

```
{
      test: /\.sass$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "postcss", "resolve-url",  "sass?sourceMap"]
    }
```

this loader setup has worked well for me so far, so i don't think the problem is there.

I tried removing this set of rules (the ones with media queries) and the rest of the sass code seems to be ok. Any hint where should I look? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is small media query a new media query or the same as medium mediaquery?

Comment: @DenisTsoi, `$small` and `$medium` are **sass variables** defined just before the media query. They store just a number of pixels.

Comment: I'm suspecting that node-sass (that's a dependency for sass-loader) is using scss to check rather than sass (I checked your code on codepen and everything seems fine)

Comment: You need to pass in  options: { indentedSyntax: true } for sass-loader webpack (node-sass has this off as default)

Comment: Throoze - did this help?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to pass in `indentedSyntax: true` through sass-loader options in order for `node-sass` to compile with `indentedSyntax`

**Example**

```
{
  test: /\.sass$/,
  loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "postcss", "resolve-url",  
  {
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      indentedSyntax: true
    }
  }]
}
```